# jQuery plugin creation and declaration for usage with $(). or $

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Simple idea: just have a plugin (more a basic function). That I can use with jQuery in different ways it offers, means:

```
var myNewVar = $.myNewFunction( myVar );
var myNewVar = $().myNewFunction( myVar );
```

I want to know if what I did is the good way to doesn't repeat the code, or if their is a better way to.

Here my plugin:

```
// New function to jquery to change an array (from form) to an object
$.formArrayToObject = function( array ) {
    var form = {};
    $(array).each(function(){
        if( !form[this.name] ) {
            form[this.name] = this.value;
        }
        else {
            if ( !Array.isArray(form[this.name]) ) {
                form[this.name] = [form[this.name]];
            }
            form[this.name].push(this.value);
        }
    });
    return form;
};

// Second declaration to be able to call both $. and $().
jQuery.fn.formArrayToObject = function() {
    $.formArrayToObject();
};
```

Comment: And I'm open to any other suggestion about my code if there is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your function - as far as I can tell - doesn't rely on a jQuery collection, I'd stick to always using "1 true way" of calling it.
I.e. I assume that

```
$("some > selector").formArrayToObject(arr) === $.formArrayToObject(arr);
```

that is, the two ways of calling it give the same exact result.

If that's the case, just use `$.yourFunction` and *only* that. Having two invocations that *should* be semantically different but actually aren't is just confusing.

For instance, jQuery doesn't have both `$.ajax()` *and* `$(...).ajax()` simply because the latter doesn't really make sense; the `$.ajax` function isn't dependent on a certain context or selector, so why would you call it as if it was?

(besides, your second declaration in the code above is broken; it ignores arguments)